# using PHP code inside LESS

Tags: php, lessphp

Is there a way to use PHP code inside LESS.

I am trying to set LESS varibale from PHP code. I tried using php code in LESS but it wont build. I am using LessPHP

```
@headerBG   = <?php echo get_option('body_bg'); ?>;
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about Tutoring with a software named Wordpress, here a Tutorial for Extending it with a specific Plugin and an individual Theme.

Comment: PHP is a server-side programming language. Of course LESS won’t build; PHP needs a server to execute it.

Comment: ...or an interpreter.

Comment: I am using LessPHP to build my LESS

Comment: Not sure why you changed your whole question, I thought asking about how the cache gets rebuilt was more valid.. It looks like it _should_ get rebuilt if any of the vars you set during the `less_vars` filter changes

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use PHP code *inside* LESS.

What comes perhaps *closest* is that you [create your own function in PHP that you register and then use in lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#custom_functions).

---

*Long Version:* You can not just expect that only by putting something that looks like PHP code will be interpreted in a less file.

I've double-checked that with [the official syntax of LESS](http://lesscss.org/#docs) in [lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/) and I can not find *any* reference that tells this could even be possible.

Which makes me wonder a bit why you ask the question as I would normally think that those references are checked at first but probably you haven't had the time.

So please let me know to which reference you were referring to that said you can place PHP code into less files.

Comment: please check here https://github.com/sanchothefat/wp-less/blob/master/wp-less.php line 154, it says `automatically regenerate if vars have changed`. Is it checking LESS variable or LessPHP variable array ?

Comment: According to your tests, you have already answered that. You have removed this from your original question, but your testings showed that PHP variables are not related to that information. If you find the wording subtle vague, you can also ask the person who has written the lines. That person might be also interested in your feedback so that the documentation can be improved. So better ask there first.